# Error: Must specify a primary resource (JAR or Python file) - Spark submit Python app

Tags: python, deployment, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to complete one simple task. I have set of workers. I want to deploy zip-archive, which contains set of `python files`. Then, I want to send some `command`, and, after some time, I want to get the result.

Anyway, I submit my files to workers:

```
spark-submit --master spark://User-PC:7077 --py-files deploy.zip --name ParserExecutor
```

I have the error:

```
Error: Must specify a primary resource (JAR or Python file)
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
```

The `deploy.zip` contains `ParserExecutor.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this >>
       spark-submit --master spark://User-PC:7077 --py-files deploy.zip --name ParserExecutor ParserExecutor.py

Comment: I don't think this works. I get `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Spark 1.3.0+ you could also execute:

```
./spark-submit ParserExecutor.py
```